# What is the rank of the matrix in this situation?

Tags: matrices

$A$ is a $9$ by $9$ matrix in the field modulo $5$ ($\mathbb{Z}/5$). It is known that the number of solutions for the equation $Ax=0$ is between $40$ and $150$. I need to find out the rank of the matrix in this situation I tried but I have never encountered a question like that before. Thanks for any help!!

Comment: The kernel of $A$ defines a vector space, so it is either trivial or has uncountably many elements. Are you working over a finite field, otherwise the question doesn't make sense?

Comment: In which field is this supposed to happen? In an infinite field, the solutions are a subspace, o the number of solutions is either $1$ if $A$ is non-singular, or infinite.

Comment: my field is finite and it is modulo 5 Z5

Comment: OK, so, as the comments say, the solutions form a  vector space over the field of 5 elements. Do you know anything about the number of elements of such a vector space?

Comment: never heard such a term as vector space.

Comment: So, have you had the time to digest the answers that have been posted?

Comment: Earth to shadi, come in, please.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel of the matrix is a vector subspace of $(\mathbb{Z}/5)^9$.  So, it must be isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/5)^k$ for some $0\leq k\leq 9$.  The rank of the matrix is the dimension of the range minus the dimension of the kernel.

Comment: what does kernel mean?

Comment: @shadihelf The kernel is the set of vectors that the matrix maps to the zero vector.  Some call it the nullspace.

Comment: Does the number of solutions for A*x=0 mean kernel of a matrix?

Comment: @shadihelf Yes.

Comment: What is the dimension of the kernel mean?

Comment: @shadihelf Do you know what the dimension of a vector space is?

Comment: No.But Im pretty sure that it has to do with the number of solutions

Comment: is the nullity here 8?

Comment: @shadihelf Did Gerry Myerson's answer help?

Comment: sort of...but since we never had these questions in class it took some time to digest the answer

Answer (score 0):

Let me write $F_5$ for the field of five elements.

Now, suppose $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_r$ are all solutions of $Ax=0$, and suppose $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_r$ are all elements of $F_5$. Then $c_1x_1+c_2x_2+\cdots+c_rx_r$ is also a solution, because $$A(c_1x_1+c_2x_2+\cdots+c_rx_r)=c_1Ax_1+c_2Ax_2+\cdots+c_rAx_r=c_10+c_20+\cdots+c_r0=0$$

So, if the equation has one non-zero solution, $x_1$, then it has at least 5 solutions, all the items of the form $c_1x_1$ for $c_1$ in $F_5$.

Now suppose it has another solution, $x_2$, in addition to those 5 solutions. Then it has at least 25 solutions, namely, all the items of the form $c_1x_1+c_2x_2$ for $c_1$ and $c_2$ in $F_5$.

And, if it has more than these 25 solutions, then let $x_3$ be a different solution. Then it has at least 125 solutions, namely, all the items of the form $c_1x_1+c_2x_2+c_3x_3$ with $c_1,c_2,c_3$ all in $F_5$.

And so on. The bottom line is that the number of solutions must be a power of 5. It must be one of the numbers $1,5,25,125,625,\dots$.

So knowing there are between 40 and 150 solutions, you should now be able to work out exactly how many solutions it has.

As for working out the rank, I'm finding that harder to do without using concepts unfamiliar to OP such as vector space and (I assume) dimension. Actually, I'd like to know what definition of rank OP is using, if those concepts are out of reach. But here goes.

There's a theorem that says rank plus nullity equals number of columns. Nullity is the largest number of linearly independent solutions of $Ax=0$. The reasoning we went through above should let you work out how many linearly independent solutions $Ax=0$ has. And since you know the number of columns, that will be enough to figure out the rank.

But, really --- what definition are you using for the rank of a matrix?

Comment: I have to find the rank and the question mark is my mistake

Comment: are x1,x2,x3 the nullity of the matrix in this situation?

Comment: No. Nullity is a *number*. It is the number of linearly independent solutions of $Ax=0$. $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are linearly independent solutions and, if there aren't any more, then that says the nullity is 3.